# vb.net database/storing questions

Tags: xml, database, vb.net, listbox, storage

I am wriing a vb.net windows application to log and store information. then display it in a sortable multiple column listbox (I personally like [FlexGrid](http://www.componentone.com/superproducts/flexgridwinforms/) by [Component One](http://www.componentone.com/)).

Example:
http://www.rptsoftware.com/help/microsoft_access_thirdparty/images/msflexgrid2small.jpg

However... I am not sure how to go about storing the information.

Should I go with a .sdf file database, registry, simply storing them in a file, or some other method?

What I need is to be able to:

read/write/delete from it

read possibly up to a 20mb file and sorting it without a lot of lag

be transported to multiple systems and maintain these writes (installed on many systems)

I know I could split up the reading/writing to anther thread. Even to other .DLL's and whatnot. But as for storing. Not sure what the best option is.

Any ideas?
-Patrick

Comment: Is your 20MB file the size of the XML file you're looking to import, or the size of the storage source for all of your information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something lightweight and portable theb you should take a look at [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/). There's a driver for .NET which you can download from:

> [System.Data.SQLite - An open source ADO.NET provider for the SQLite database engine](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/)

Another alternative is to use an Access database. If you have a copy of Microsoft Office that has an Access license then you can create the bare bones of the database then hook it up to your application. You don't need further copies of Access for your code to run on other computers to access the database file itself.

Comment: Hmm it seems that nvarchar has a limit of 50? I will be storing clipboard data for one, and it would be much longer than 50 chars.

Comment: It seems i have run into a small problem. Just using a simple adaptor after creating the database, tables and whatnot. I execute this commend:
`HistoryTableAdapter.Insert(1, Date.Now, "Testing")`

And I get this unhandled error:
`File opened that is not a database file
file is encrypted or is not a database`